# 全文検索エンジンにおいて、ユーザーごとに検索対象を絞る仕組みについてどのような仕組みが考えられるか

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

ユーザーが検索対象コンテンツをブックマークできるシステムがあり、検索対象コンテンツの検索を全文検索エンジンを用いて提供するとします。
すべてのコンテンツではなく、特定のユーザーがブックマークしているコンテンツ内に絞って検索を提供する場合の仕組みにどのようなものがあるのかお知恵を拝借したいです。

ユーザーのブックマーク可能コンテンツ数には制限がかかっておらず、数万を超えることもあると想定します。

検索時にコンテンツに振られているIDで絞るなどもできるかなと思うのですが、ブックマーク数が多いとパフォーマンスが低下するなどがあるかと考えます。

全文検索エンジン側のコンテンツドキュメントに配列などで誰がブックマークしているかを持たせるという方法も考えましたが、ドキュメント更新頻度の増加やパフォーマンス的に問題ないのかが気になっています。